# How to add javascript to SharePoint 2013 article page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a SharePoint 2013 article Page. In this article page, I also want to embed custom JavaScript functionality for some menu and navigation stuff. I am trying to add this, but it seems that the SharePoint 2013 source editor removes all the JavaScript tags and gives an error saying that it is not allowed in HTML.

I am also trying to add an external JS file, but it is of no use either, as it gets removed as well.

How do I get this to work on this body-only simple html page?

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload your javascript file to a SharePoint Library.
2. Add content editor webpart in your artile page.
3. Click edit web part and provide the link of the JS file in the Content Link.

[How to I add a simple jquery slider to a Sharepoint 2010 web part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761284/how-to-i-add-a-simple-jquery-slider-to-a-sharepoint-2010-web-part)

Comment: SharePoint 2013 also has a `Script Editor` web part that can be used instead of the `Content Editor` web part